# Generating a PAR curve from Bond Price Inputs

Tags: programming, quantlib, yield-curve

I am a brand new user to QuantLib and I am running it in Python.

I am attempting to generate a PAR yield curve from  time to maturity and price input as shown here

'time to maturity': ['30-03-2020','30-12-2020', '15-06-2021', '17-10-2022', '17-04-2023'],
'bond price': [99.44, 99.88, 101.98, 108.70, 96.46]

I am struggling to find the Quantlib functions required to generate the output for me to plot the curve.
Any help here or an example  will be great.

Comment: Hi and welcome; unfortunately, there seems to be a bit of input missing, e.g. the coupon rate of the bonds and the curve evaluation date. Please look here: https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/termstructures.html#fittedbondcurve

Comment: Thank-you ! I will include these inputs and see how far I get

Answer (score 1):

You could try FinancePy.

https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy

Here's a notebook that does this.

https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy/blob/master/notebooks/products/bonds/FINBONDYIELDCURVE_FittingToBondMarketPrices.ipynb

Comment: Thanks Dom, appreciate your answer!  I need to generate the  PAR curve using the QuantLib functions...Will  I need to use , the schedule function, rate helpers and term structure to generate the curve from the price inputs ?

Comment: Not an expert on QL. best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Quantlib Python Cookbook by Goutham Balaraman and Luigi Ballabio is also an excellent reference book.

Comment: Thanks. I will get on that book straight away !! Can anybody describe the use of the QuantLib FixedRateBondHelper function ?